# Facebook not responding to Javascript API calls

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to use Facebook's Javascript SDK to get a user's login status when my page is displayed.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      alert('Logged in');
    } else {

      alert('Need to log in!');
    }
  });
```

I go through the Facebook initialization without problems, and the FB.getLoginStatus() function gets called, but apparently the Facebook server does not respond. I do not receive a response of any kind.

I did put my application's ID into the initialization function, and the initialization code is downloaded from Facebook. I am debugging on Firefox using Firebug, so I know the initialization is successful and the FB.getLoginStatus() call is being made. I am simply not getting the response back from the server.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why I am not getting this response? If so, please advise.

ADDITION:

In response to Sahil Mittal's request, the entire code is provided below. It should be noted that there really isn't much more to see...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : XXXXXXXXXXXX,
  status     : true,
  xfbml      : true
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      alert('Logged in');
    } else {

      alert('Need to Log In');
    }
  });
</script>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Well this seems to be impossible. Please share your whole code so that we may help you better!

Comment: Did you check your console log for any errors?

Comment: Actually, the log seems to say that FB is not defined. That is strange: isn't FB defined in Facebook's Javascript SDK code???

Comment: The SDK gets loaded _asychronously_ (when embedded this way) – and to _wait_ for that to have finished, is exactly what the `window.fbAsyncInit` event handler _is for_ … so put your `FB.getLoginStatus` into there, after the `FB.init` …

Answer (score 0):

credit for this answer should go to CBroe. I wish that CBroe had put this as an answer so that I could give proper credit.

Nevertheless, the answer to this question is to place all FB functions inside the window.fbAsyncInit() function, as in the following example:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : XXXXXXXXXXXXX,
  status     : false,
  xfbml      : true
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
      alert('Logged in');
    } else {

      alert('Need to Log In');
    }
  });
};
```

This is not well documented on Facebook (what else is new???), so I am posting this so that other Facebook newbies can avoid the frustration and delay that I experienced.

Again: thanks should go to CBroe for this answer.